# How to write code that calls a WCF service and falls back from Kerberos to NTLM if needed?

Tags: wcf, sharepoint, authentication, kerberos, ntlm

I need to call a WCF service programmatically. The service may be hosted with **either NTLM or Kerberos authentication** and needs to work under either. That is, if connecting to the service via Kerberos fails, then it should fall back to NTLM.

Here's the code I'm using for Kerberos auth (if relevant, the service is hosted in SharePoint 2010 and is being called from a web part):

```
public static SiteMembershipSvc.SiteMembershipServiceClient InitialiseSiteMembershipService(string url)
{
    var binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
    binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly;
    binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Windows;
    url = url.EndsWith("/") ? url + SiteMembershipAddress : url + "/" + SiteMembershipAddress;
    var endpoint = new EndpointAddress(url);
    var proxy = new SiteMembershipSvc.SiteMembershipServiceClient(binding, endpoint);
    proxy.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;
    return proxy;
}
```

Calling a method on the proxy when run in an NTLM environment gives the error:

> The HTTP request is unauthorized with
>   client authentication scheme
>   'Negotiate'. The authentication header
>   received from the server was 'NTLM'.

Note: The URL may be in another web application on another server. I can't check what authentication the web part's web app runs under and assume it is the same as where the WCF service is hosted.

**How can I (automatically or manually) ensure authentication falls back from Kerberos back to NTLM on failure?**

***Update:***

As mentioned, the authentication error occurs when a web method is called. However I don't want to wait that long as there are several web methods in the service called from several places. I'd like to test the authentication at the point where the proxy is configured (in the code snippet above).

I've tried using `proxy.Open()` but that doesn't seem to cause the failure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't been able to find a way to do this automatically. Instead I've added UI to the application where the type of authentication must be chosen.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit off a curveball, but why is it falling back to NTLM.  I've had significant difficulty with security in active directory and WCF all related to service principal names (SPNs).

Kerberos will fail if you are running the service as something other than Network Service unless you have an SPN declared in the domain for your service.  To set the SPN you need the windows server administrative kit, which has the command setspn.

```
setspn -A HTTP\machinename domain\service_account
```

This will then allow Kerberos to share client credentials to your service within the domain.

Please do some reading, as you could break kerberos for any other services running on the same box depending on your setup.

Comment: Well it's more that I want it to try Kerberos first and if that fails then use NTLM. I was hoping using Kerberos auth would automatically do this but it doesn't seem to.

Comment: My first assumption as well.  The way to think about it is if any service in the enterprise was trusted, then you could have a rogue service steal credentials, impersonate and do naughty things.  The SPN forces the enterprise admin to say that this service is trusted to have your kerberos credential, otherwise don't ask for it.

Comment: That's good to know. I've reframed the question a little as I don't think it was quite clear. I need the web part to 'auto-select' the correct authentication depending on whether the service is hosted in Kerberos or Windows auth.

Answer (score 1):

(I recognize the original post is very old.)

Can you use something other than BasicHttpBinding (like WsHttpBinding)?  According to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733836(v=vs.110).aspx) article, BasicHttpBinding is the one exception to the binding objects, in that it does not automatically negotiate.  This is why allowNTLM has no effect.

Comment: Didn't know that and it looks like WsHttpBinding would have been OK to use in SharePoint. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error msg which I posted about [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/d366d1cd-b005-4122-b035-54a529ba5da0/#31e82e7e-21c5-45c6-9577-fbe6221cb823) and solved it by creating a dynamic endpoint like so:

```
public static SiteMembershipSvc.SiteMembershipServiceClient InitialiseSiteMembershipService(string url)
{
    //create endpoint
    EndpointAddress ep = new EndpointAddress(new Uri(string), EndpointIdentity.CreateUpnIdentity("MyDomain\WCFRunAsUser"));
    //create proxy with new endpoint
    SiteMembershipSvc.SiteMembershipServiceClient service = new SiteMembershipSvc.SiteMembershipServiceClient("wsHttp", ep);
    //allow client to impersonate user
    service.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;
    //return our shiny new service
    return service;
}
```

I was running the WCF service as a specific Active Directory user rather than the default NETWORK_SERVICE.

Comment: That's cool but I need to pass through the credentials of the current user to the web service.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting:

`proxy.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowNTLM = true;`

According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.security.windowsclientcredential.allowntlm.aspx), AllowNTLM is now obsolete - i'm not sure what the correct alternative is.

Comment: Luckily I'm using .NET 3.5 where it's not marked obsolete. I'll give it a try - thanks!

Comment: I checked this out and found that AllowNTLM defaults to true so unfortunately this didn't work. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using the full dns name of the server as the address of the service. Try using the NETBIOS name or the IP address. That should force it to use NTLM.

If you know what protocol the server is using you can configure your app to use either the full name or the ip.

Hope that works for you.

Comment: You're right, I am using the DNS name. That's my only option because the system is load balanced and I forgot to mention that the WCF service is hosted in SharePoint - it will only respond to requests on that DNS name.

Answer (score 0):

If your Kerberos fail it will automatically default to NTLM, you don't have to do anything special.

http://www.windowsecurity.com/articles/Troubleshooting-Kerberos-SharePoint-environment-Part1.html

http://www.windowsecurity.com/articles/Troubleshooting-Kerberos-SharePoint-environment-Part2.html

http://www.windowsecurity.com/articles/Troubleshooting-Kerberos-SharePoint-environment-Part3.html

Comment: This isn't the case. If I specify `HttpClientCredentialType.Windows` I get the error written in the question.